# What's wrong with this derivation?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, partial-derivative, change-of-variable, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose I have the following cdf for random variable $e$: $F_e(t)=Pr(e<t)$. The support of $e$ is the real line.

I could always do the following identity transformation by adding a parameter $r$ on both sides of the inequality and rearrange:
$F_e(t)=Pr(e<t)=Pr(r<t+r-e)=Pr(r<t+m)=Pr(-m<t-r)=F_{-m}(t-r)$, where $m=r-e$.

Now suppose I do partial derivative of $F_{-m}(t-r)$ with respect to $r$, if I do it using $F_{-m}(t-r)$, it gives me $\frac{\partial F_{-m}(t-r)}{\partial r}=f_{-m}(t-r)\times(-1)$, where $f_{-m}(\cdot)$ is the pdf of $-m$. However, if I do partial derivative with respect to $F_e(t)$, since it does not depend on $r$,$\frac{\partial F_e(t)}{\partial r}=0$, which is obviously a contradiction because $F_e(t)=F_{-m}(t-r)$ and thus they should have the same partial derivatives.

What's wrong with my derivation and reasoning, and how to correctly calculate $\frac{\partial F_{-m}(t-r)}{\partial r}$ (and show that it indeed equals zero)?

Comment: Because $m$ depends on $r$.

Comment: I am not sure how to read "$F_{-m}(t-r)$".    Presumably $-m$ is supposed to be a random variable, apparently equal to $e-r$, but seems to suggest $r$ is constant. You then take a partial derivative with respect to $r$.  Does $-m$ change with $r$ or not?

Comment: "... because $F_e(t)=F_{-m}(t-r)$ and thus they should have the same partial derivatives." What do you think this means? In what sense is $F_{-m}(t-r)$ a function of $r$? Yes, I see the symbol $r$ right there, but I don't see any function of which $r$ is the first parameter or the second parameter or any other parameter--there is no function $f$ in sight for which I could write $\partial f/\partial r$. Likewise for $F_e(t)$. Before you ask whether the partial derivatives are equal, first ask how they can even be defined.

Comment: @IH Thanks! I think you are right. Given that $m$ also depends on $r$, how could I obtain $\frac{\partial F_{-m}(t-r)}{\partial r}$ correctly? I'm thinking about chain-rule, but do not see how to proceed to show this partial derivative equals zero.

Comment: @Henry Thanks! Based on HI's comment, I guess $-m$ should change with $r$. How to take the partial derivative then?

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the comment. For any function $f(x)$, I could always redefine it as $g(x,y)=f(x)$ whose partial derivative with respect to $y$ should be zero by definition, right? It simply means $f(x)$ does not change along the $y$ direction.

Comment: Yes, the way to use partial derivatives is to define exactly what your multiple-variable functions are, you'll either define both of your functions so that they have the same partial derivatives, or you'll have two different functions that just happen to intersect at one point. But you actually need to have a very clear definition of those multiple-variable functions.